# Visual C++ 2008 - breakpoint cannot be hit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I am trying to dissect a legacy application through debugging, but I can't get the breakpoint to hit in certain places of the application. The application has a c# GUI frontend and a c++ backend.

I am trying to put a breakpoint in a c++ project of the solution. There are a couple of c++ projects, but I cannot set a breakpoint in one of them. I tried deleting bin/obj files but had no luck.

Afterwards I checked debug > windows > modules, and then noticed that the dll for that particular project is not being shown. The program executes correctly, but perhaps since there is no entry for that project shown in debug > windows > modules, a breakpoint cannot be set. The problem is, I don't know how to make a fix to this problem. Can anyone give a helping hand?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to enable unmanaged code debugging.  Try the follownig

- Right click on the C# project and select Properties
- Go to the Debug tab
- Check "Enable Unmanaged Code Debugging"